# Does html picture tag saves bandwidth

Tags: html, image

currently i am using  big images using `<img>` tag to fit for all screen sizes. If i use `<picture>` tag will it saves bandwidth or page loading time when small image will load for small screen?

Need opinion please.

Comment: It is still the same image, you need to compress the image or resize it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](https://i.imgur.com/3ppJhiE.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time. You also have a preview pane below, which would have alerted you that your question didn't make any sense because tags were not being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the same, single source as in the example below (which wouldn't make sense anyway), then **no**.

```
<picture>
    <img srcset="default.jpg" alt="Default">
</picture>
```

If you are talking about using different image sources, then **yes**. A browser will only load the most appropriate image for the current media. E.g. ([source](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-html5-picture-for-responsive-images--cms-21015)):

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="smaller_landscape.jpg" media="(max-width: 40em) and (orientation: landscape)">
    <source srcset="smaller_portrait.jpg" media="(max-width: 40em) and (orientation: portrait)">
    <source srcset="default_landscape.jpg" media="(min-width: 40em) and (orientation: landscape)">
    <source srcset="default_portrait.jpg" media="(min-width: 40em) and (orientation: portrait)">
    <img srcset="default_landscape.jpg" alt="My default image">
</picture>
```

Note that you'll need a [polyfill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/) to use `picture` in IE.

Answer (score 0):

No. A `picture` tag requires more characters to type than an `img` tag so it will take up more (although not significantly more) bandwidth.

You might be conflating the `picture` element with [responsive images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images) (which can be achieved using both `picture` and `img` elements).

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable links and comments.

Comment: Even though there is nothing wrong in the content of your answer, it does give out the vibe that you cannot save bandwidth with a `picture` tag - even though your second paragraph brings some nuance. I would argue that `picture` together with `source` can indeed save bandwidth. I think that's what OP was after, but didn't get it worded correctly.

Comment: @BramVanroy — As the second paragraph says, you can use responsive images using `srcset` and the `<img>` element. The `<picture>` element doesn't have to be involved.

Comment: I know. As I said it just seems that putting out a fat 'no' is not the right approach IMO, as it seems OP wants to use IMG and srcset / picture with source in which case it is true that bandwidth is saved.